# Emacs window configuration like awesome wm

Tags: window, window-splitting

Does there exist anything like awesomewm window configurations in emacs? For example, having custom layouts for two windows, maybe 1, 2, and 3, the first being even vertical split, the second even horizontal split, and the third being something like 1/3-2/3 vertical split. And so on for three windows and above. I've looked but have yet to find anything having this functionality.

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-window-manager